# How to Bind controller to multidimensional query string parameter in .NET Core/5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net5

I have a web client which uses jQuery data tables for server side pagination and ordering. It sends parameters in a specific way through a query string:

Here is an exmpaple of the order parameter that is sent to the server:

```
&order[0][column]=1&order[0][dir]=asc&start=0&length=10&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&_=1618229879540
```

I'm having a really hard time trying to bind to these parameters in an ApiController class.

Controller code:

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<DataTable<Audit>>> GetAudits([FromQuery]DataTableParams dataTableParams)
        {
            var audits = await _auditRepository.GetAuditsAsync(dataTableParams);

            return Ok(audits);
        }
```

Parameter Classes:

```
    public class DataTableParams
    {
        public int Draw { get; set; }
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; } = 30;
        public string Dir { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DtOrder> Order { get; set;}
    }

    public class DtOrder
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Column to which ordering should be applied.
        /// This is an index reference to the columns array of information that is also submitted to the server.
        /// </summary>
        public int Column { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ordering direction for this column.
        /// It will be dt-string asc or dt-string desc to indicate ascending ordering or descending ordering, respectively.
        /// </summary>
        public string Dir { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried DtOrder[] instead of IEnumerable. In each case the framework fails to bind to the order parameter, lenght/count is 0.

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for this exact thing.

1. Datatables sends the data in a specific formatted query string.
2. There does not appear to be an easy way to bind the data a custom binder needs to be created for this.

There is a NuGet package that specifically deals with helping format and response to datatables requests. DataTables.AspNet.AspNetCore is the package and it has a binder and everything needed to be able to bind to database query strings as well as format the response for datatables.